Prove a periodic closed form on a torus becomes exact if you subtract its average
Let $\mathbb{T}^n$ be the $n$-torus, and $$\omega:=\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i dx^i\in\Omega^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$$ closed. Furthermore define $$\bar{\omega}:=\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{\omega_i}dx^i$$ where $\bar{\omega_i}$ is just the average of $\omega_i$ over the torus.
I am trying to show that the form $\omega-\bar{\omega}$ is exact. I've tried explicitly coming up with an $f$ such that $df=\omega-\bar{\omega}$, but to no avail, so I'm guessing I need to somehow show existence, but I don't really know any sufficient criteria for a form to be exact. I've tried showing that the integral over any closed path is 0, but that hasn't worked out either.
Any help is appreciated.

Your idea to integrate over a closed path works out fine. Put an invariant measure on the group $G=(S^1)^n=\Bbb T^n$ with measure $1$. Then $$ \int_\gamma\tilde\omega=\int_\gamma\left(\int_G g^\omega,dg\right) =\int_G g^\left(\int_\gamma\omega\right)dg = \int_\gamma\omega.$$

@TedShifrin I see. Does this use the fact that $\omega$ is closed? I'm sure it does, because otherwise we'd have non-closed exact forms, but I can't see where.

Yeah, what I wrote doesn't quite make sense. The usual argument is that because $G$ is compact, the exponential map $\mathfrak g\to G$ is onto and $L_g$ is homotopic to the identity. Hence $\int_\gamma L_g^*\omega = \int_\gamma\omega$ for closed forms $\omega$ by homotopy invariance.

You can adapt the method of page 211 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf to get a formula for $f$ such that $df = \bar{\omega} - \omega$. I'll give my thoughts on how to apply it here. Your case is a lot simpler than in that book.
For each $g = (g_1, \dots, g_n) \in \mathbb{T}^n$, find a family  $g(t) \in \mathbb{T}^n$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$ with $g(0) = 0$, $g(1) = g$. Let's use $g(t) = tg$. Then define diffeomorphisms $F_{g, t}(x) = x + g(t)$ on $\mathbb{T}^n$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$F_{g, 1}^*\omega - F_{g, 0}^*\omega = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{d}{dt}F_{g, t}^{*}\omega\,dt,$$
$$\omega(x + g) - \omega(x) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{d}{dt}F_{g, t}^{*}\omega(x)\,dt.$$
Using Cartan's formula (explained in the book), when $d\omega = 0$, the RHS is $\int_{0}^{1}dF_{g,t}^{*}(\omega \lrcorner g)\,dt = d\int_{0}^{1}F_{g,t}^{*}(\omega \lrcorner g)\,dt$. Then integrating both sides with respect to $g \in \mathbb{T}^n$ yields that
$$\bar{\omega} - \omega = d\int_{\mathbb{T}^n}\int_{0}^{1}F_{g,t}^{*}(\omega \lrcorner g)\,dt\,dg = d\int_{\mathbb{T}^n}\int_{0}^{1}\langle \omega(x + tg), g \rangle\,dt\,dg.$$
